# Regex module python to extract contents

Tags: python, regex, parsing, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get the content of the variable 'html' from a javascript response. I am using the regex module to extract the html but I got 'None' as output.

```
response = 'var port_statistics = (function(window, undefined) {

function loadScript(url, callback) {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.async = true;
    script.src = url;
    var entry = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    entry.parentNode.insertBefore(script, entry);
    script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = function() {
        var rdyState = script.readyState;
        if (!rdyState || /complete|loaded/.test(script.readyState)) {
            callback();
            script.onload = null;
            script.onreadystatechange = null;
        }
    };
}

function injectCss(css) {
    var style = document.createElement('style');
    style.type = 'text/css';
    css = css.replace(/\}/g, "}\n");
    if (style.styleSheet) {
        style.styleSheet.cssText = css;
    } else {
        style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
    }
    var entry = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    entry.parentNode.insertBefore(style, entry);
}

var port_statistics = {};
var html = ["<div class=\"results_section\">", ", "
<div class='\"heading\"'> Overview </div> ",

 #HERE THE CONTENT I AM TRYING TO GET

 , "", "</div>", "", "", "</div>"].join('\n');

var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = html;
var appendTo = document.getElementById('tag-port_statistics-widget');

appendTo.parentNode.insertBefore(div, appendTo);

loadScript('https://connect.url.com//jquery-1.11.1.min.js', function() {

    portWidget.$(function () {
        portWidget.$('tr.parent')
            .click(function () {
                portWidget.$(this).siblings('.child-' + this.id).fadeToggle('slow');
                portWidget.$(this).find('.plus').toggle();
                portWidget.$(this).find('.minus').toggle();
            });
    });
});

return port_statistics;

})(window);'

prog=re.search("var html = [.*?].join('\n');", response)
print(prog) #Output: None
```

I also tried this:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser')
print(soup.prettify())
div_search = re.search('["<div class=\"results_section\">",(.*), "</div>"]', soup.prettify(), re.IGNORECASE)
print(div_search.group(0)) #Output: v
```

How can I do it to get the content of the variable 'html', please?
In the second part, I would like to use this content to parse the content of the HTML tag with BeautifulSoup.

Thank you.

***EDIT***

I am trying to get this:

```
  "<div class=\"results_section\">", ", "
<div class='\"heading\"'> Overview </div> ",

 #HERE THE CONTENT I AM TRYING TO GET

 , "", "</div>", "", "", "</div>"
```

Comment: post the output you want.

Comment: Hi @宏杰李, I edited my answer. I am trying to get the data inside the array of the variable called 'html'. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
result = re.search(r'var html = \[(.+?)\]', response, re.DOTALL)
print(result.group(1))
```

> '.'
>
> (Dot.) In the default mode, this matches any character **except a
>   newline.** If the **DOTALL** flag has been specified, this matches any
>   character **including a newline**.

Your text contain newline, you need use DOTALL to match.

Comment: Thank you! Actually there were tags like: '<span> [+]</span>', I used this: 'result = re.search(r'var html = \["<.*>"\]', html, re.DOTALL)' and it is working perfectly!

Comment: The var to html part is done by JavaScrip, I try to do it in python and it do not work.

Comment: ok thanks, I used many times split() and join() functions, it works but it it not that efficient..

Comment: yes, that may works. please accept this answer to close this question.